# MySql get count(*) with a join from a table

Tags: php, mysql

Mostly not able to think through what to do,

I have two database tables. Say table_employee and table_workorder

every employee have one/many workorder.

Earlier i was using to queries, one to get employee tuple from table_employee and other query for every employee workorder count.

```
SELECT * from table_employee order by " . $orderBy ." desc"
SELECT count(*) as wcount from table_workorder where employeeid = " . $table_employee.id;
```

I realized instead of 2 DB calls, it would be nice to have a single call that can fetch me results, but i am unable to frame the query. Trying in MySql coupled with PHP

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and your desired outcome?

Comment: -1 ? seriously... ? you gotta be kidding me... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.employeeid), 0) AS wcount
FROM table_employee AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_workorder AS t2 ON t2.employeeid = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY $orderBy DESC
```

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you'll get rows for employees with no work orders.

Here's how this works:

1. JOIN creates a cross-product between the two tables, relating them using the `ON t2.employeeid = t1.id` condition.
2. Since it's a `LEFT JOIN`, any rows in the first table with no matching row in the second table will be put in the result set, with `NULL` for all the columns in the second table.
3. It groups these results by the `t1.id` column, so there will be a single row in the final results for each group.
4. For each group, it counts all the rows with non-null `t2.employeeid`. As mentioned in step 2, the employees with no matching work orders will get `NULL` for `t2.employeeid`, so they won't be counted.
5. Since this count will be `NULL` if nothing was found, we use `IFNULL` to convert that to `0` to get a more useful result.
6. The final results are ordered by the `$orderBy` column.

This is exactly what your sequence of queries does, but it's all done in one SQL query.

Here's a good tutorial on SQL JOINs:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: it looks complicated.. i wish i could understand it and then write it .. can you go through some explanation

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a teacher, I'm not going to try to explain how JOINs work. I've added a link to a popular web page about it. Good luck, you need to learn the basics.

Comment: fair enough...i have been avoiding revisiting that.. but thanks

Comment: A moment of weakness :)

Comment: Works like a charm..  i was afraid this was complex, but looks like trick was the "group by" Thank you again :)